# jQuery selector to grab previous div when input in current div has focus

Tags: jquery

I have the following html structure

```
<div id="container">
  <div class="label">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.SomeProperty) 
  </div>
  <div class="input">
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.SomeProperty) 
  </div>
<!--on and on-->
</div>
```

What I want to do is set a background-color on the label div, when the input in the corresponding div has focus.

In other words, when the user clicks on (or tabs to) the textbox for SomeProperty, I want to highlight the label for SomeProperty by adding a css class to the labels div.

I know I can set class="SomeProperty" on the label div and then have some jQuery to add some css like this:

```
$('#container input').focus(function () {
  var thisId = $(this).attr('id');
  $('.' + thisId).addClass('highlight');
  //...
});
```

But I'm wondering if there is a better way.  I don't really want to assign classes to all the label div's as it seems sloppy and maybe hard to maintain down the road.

The way I see it, I want to write a script that can jump up one level, and then grab the previous sibling, probably some combination of parent() and prev(), but I've not been able to get it right. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest, if the `.label` element will *always* precede the `.input` element:

```
$('#container input').focus(function(){
    $(this).closest('div').prev('div.label').addClass('highlight');
});
```

Or, to allow a more flexible DOM-independent approach:

```
$('#container input').focus(function(){
    $('div.label[for="' + this.id + '"]').addClass('highlight');
});
```

Comment: @Sushanth: while I appreciate the intent to help, your edit would have broken the code, the `focus` can only take effect on the `input`, which is contained within the `.input` element (hence `closest()`), using `prev()` would have selected the element preceding the `input` element (which doesn't exist), *not* the element with the *`class="input"`*.

Comment: My intent was not to edit your post .. I edited it mistaking that it was mine.. Sorry abt that :)

Comment: I like the more flexible solution, although I think this [for="' this.id '"] bit is breaking things.  I'm hoping for something that isn't specific to element types or class names, as these may change over time.  The fact that the label will always immediately precede the input can be taken as a given, however.  Thanks for your response!

Comment: @Forty-Two: sorry, I'm an idiot, and forgot to concatenate...edited and fixed!

Answer (score 0):

You can approach this in two ways..

One is using .find() on the .closest()

**Or this**

Using **.prev()**

```
$('#container input').focus(function(){
    $(this).closest('.input').prev('.label').addClass('highlight');
});
```

using **.prevAll()**

```
   $('#container input').focus(function(){
        $(this).closest('.input').prevAll('.label').first().addClass('highlight');
    });
```